# Show only unique columns in repeater control using asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to bind repeater control from database. But i need to bind repeater with unique column. 
eg.

```
Mumbai, Haryana, Goa, Haryana, Mumbai
```

to
`Mumbai, Haryana, Goa`

My code is given below.

```
SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection("myconnection");
        string strcon = "select * from indiapincodes where statename =@statename";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strcon, con3);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statename", erouting);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "emp");
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        con3.Close();
        con3.Dispose();
```

Above code is working good but i want to know how to filter column with unique value and fill in repeater. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show output of query?

Comment: Output is "Mumbai, Haryana, Goa, Haryana, Mumbai" but i want to remove repeated value from repeater such as mumbai and haryana are showing 2 times

Comment: Are those column names or string data or rows? What is it?

Comment: The better approach is to filter the data before bind it to repeater control. Using distinct keyword to filter the duplicated data

Comment: You are displaying only one column value in the repeater? If yes then you should use DISTINCT in the Sql query .the will return unique values for that column matching criteria in where clause.

Answer (score -1):

```
string strcon = "SELECT DISTINCT columnname from indiapincodes WHERE statename=@statename";
```